# Change base of numeric system in Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, math, linear-algebra, radix

I am using [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) to solve equations in linear algebra. By default it uses base-10 numeric system. But I want to use base-3 system. Is there an API for doing it? Or should I use a different library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh?  I'm not sure this question makes sense.

`int`, `double`, and the like are all independent of base systems.  It's only when you do input/output, and convert to/from `String`, that the base matters.

...So basically, just use Apache like you would normally, and just output the results in base 3...?

Comment: I read your answer and I realized how stupid I sounded when I asked the question. ;) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the math in base 10, and then convert it base 3 when outputting it. The "base" of a number is merely a representation.

If you need help converting from base 10 to any other base, let me know, and I will point you in the right direction.